# Symfony Form multiple range field

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I need to make a search form where I need a range slider so a user could choose price_from and price_to. [Something like this](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) 
What is the best way to implement it?
The only I have found is [range type field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/range.html)
It is pretty close to what I need, but it has only one value while I need two values (price_from and price_to)

Comment: Also, to prevent future down-voting of your questions: You should clearly indicate the kind of research you have already done to tackle the problem. Additionally you should try to avoid asking for "the best way" to do something, as it clearly enables subjective opinion based answers. Instead you should articulate your questions in a way that clearly show how to benchmark the answers given. Happy Coding !

Comment: If my answer solved you problem, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are are correct to assume that you need two values (min and max). When I encountered a similar problem, I created two hidden fields for the same purpose.

To fill those hidden fields with values, I used a JS library that rendered the widget and stored the user's input in the hidden form fields:

https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Comment: How do I make it in Symfony? I don't ask to write the code for me, just don't know what to start from.

Comment: Simply add two of those fields two your form: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/hidden.html